# tiff2pdf coloured

Tags: pdf, conversion

I converted some scanned `.tif` files to `.pdf` using `tiff2pdf` (libtiff version 4.0.3 )  with JPEG compression. 
Viewing them in `evince` showed a coloured (pinkish) background.

My initial thought was that my scanner was broken, but the `.tif` files are OK and so are the `.pdf` files if I do not use JPEG compression (but then the file grows very big).

How can I get a  `.pdf` with compressed JPEG using command line tools that is not coloured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem that seemed to have been [reported around 2007](http://www.asmail.be/msg0055293066.html) and resurfaced (or else I used an older version of the library for a long time that did not have this problem).

The thing you can do is post-process the output file (assuming your `sed` has the `-i` option):

```
 tiff2pdf -j input.tif -o out.pdf
 sed -i 's|/DecodeParms << /ColorTransform 0 >>||' out.pdf
```

for some reason you get error messages and a corrupted PDF file if you leave out the `-o` option for `tiff2pdf` and pipe the output directly into `sed` (which you don't get if you do `tiff2pdf -j input.tif > out.pdf` either)

---

If you are willing to patch the tiff 4.0.4beta sources, you can either comment out lines 5160–5163 in `tools/tiff2pdf.c` (which write the `ColorTransform` stuff):

```
    /*
    if(t2p->tiff_photometric != PHOTOMETRIC_YCBCR) {
        written += t2pWriteFile(output, (tdata_t) "/DecodeParms ", 13);
        written += t2pWriteFile(output, (tdata_t) "<< /ColorTransform 0 >>\n", 24);
     }
     */
```

or change the `t2pseekproc` function to:

```
static uint64
t2p_seekproc(thandle_t handle, uint64 offset, int whence)
{
    T2P *t2p = (T2P*) handle;
    int res;
    if (t2p->outputdisable <= 0 && t2p->outputfile) {
        res = fseek(t2p->outputfile, (long) offset, whence);
        if (res == -1 && offset == 0 && whence == SEEK_END)
            return 0;
        return res;
    }
    return offset;
}
```

so that it no longer fails if you do an `fseek` from the end with offset 0 (which IMO only makes sense if a different `fseek`, with a non-zero value had preceded it, and failed).

With either these two changes all tests still pass (but they obviously don't cover all of the functionality). With the second change you can do:

```
 tiff2pdf -j | input.tif | sed -i 's|/DecodeParms << /ColorTransform 0 >>||' out.pdf
```

which IMO is less likely to break something else in `tiff2pdf` that is not tested by the test suite in the source.

Comment: Do you know why you cannot do this on one line?

Comment: @Norm the utility does an `fseek()` on stdout, that does work for redirected IO (and -o) but not for piping into another command. It does seek 0 bytes from the end when things go wrong, which seems senseless as this is normally only done if you had done an fseek that moved away from the end (which would have failed).